# Ampersand in bash script not working

Tags: bash, shell, curl, wget, ampersand

Using the Ampersand (&) to place it in the background. But in this script for some reason it doesnt work. My programming skills are not great, so please remember im a noob trying to get stuff working.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Date in format used by filenaming 
date=$(date '+%Y%m%d')

# Location where the patch files should be downloaded
patches=~/lists/patches

# Location of the full list
blacklist=~/lists/list

    while :
                    do
                            # Fetching last download date from downloaded patches
                            ldd=$(cd $patches  && printf '%s\n' * | sed "s/[^0-9]*//g"); echo $ldd
                                    if [ "$ldd" = "" ]
                                    then
                                            break
                                    else
                                            if [ "$ldd" = "$date" ]

                                                    then
                                                            break
                                                    else
                                                            ndd=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "${ldd}+1 days")

                                                            # Cant have multiple patches in $patches directory, otherwise script wont work
                                                            rm -rf $patches/*
                                                            sleep 1
                                                            file=$patches/changes-$ndd.diff.gz
                                                             curl -s -o "$file" "http://url.com/directory/name-$ndd.diff.gz" &
                                                            sleep 1

                                                            done=$(jobs -l | grep curl | wc -l)

                                                                 until [ "$done" == 1 ]
                                                                 do
                                                                    echo "still here"
                                                                 done

                                                            gunzip "$file"

                                                            # Apply patch directory to list's file directories
                                                            cat $(echo "$file" | sed "s/.gz//g") | sed 's/.\/yesterday//' | sed 's/.\/today//' > $patches/$ndd.diff
                                                            rm $(echo $file | sed "s/.gz//g")
                                                            cd $blacklist
                                                            patch -p1 --batch -r /root/fail.patch < $patches/$ndd.diff
                                                            rm /root/fail.patch
                                            fi
                                    fi
                    done
```

What i want to do is let the script wait for each command until the one before is finished. As you can see i used 'sleep' sometimes but i know that isnt a solution. I also read about the wait command, but then you have to place a command in the background using the Ampersand. And thats the problem. For some reason this script doesnt recognize the ampersand at the end of my curl command. I also tried wget, same results. Who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: why do you want send the `curl` into the background when in the next step you want wait until it finishes? Simply, remove the `&`  and the following jobchecking and youre fine...

Comment: you mean that if i dont use the `&` i'll still be able to see it using `jobs`?

Comment: No, i mean - you don't need use the `jobs` at all, because in this case here isn't any reason to send the curl into the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would never change `done` after first check. So you need to check every iteration, that's why you should test for command, not for variable
And `while` will be better, because you need to check before entering

```
 while [ "$(jobs -l | grep curl | wc -l)" -ne 0 ]; do
   echo "Still there"
   sleep 1
 done
```

I've added `sleep` because otherwise it wold just flood your console.

Comment: @jm666 Looks like he wants to know that everything is working, `wait` would just wait and wouldn't say that it's "Still there".

Comment: for me doesn't make sense sending the `curl` into BG with the `-s` switch and immediatelly after flooding the terminal every second with the "still here" message, instead of the more clean - using `curl` without `-s` (e.g. with the progressbar), without sending it into BG and without any useless `while... jobs... grep...sleep` construction. Much simpler, cleaner and far more effective...

Comment: For me too. Maybe he will add more `curl`'s later.
I don't know... He asked -- I've answered.

Comment: well thats easy to explain why i want it to be silent. I've been working on this script some time now and im constantly trying to learn new stuff and then improve my script. At the end i want to be able to run the script and only see the messages i wrote using echo. I dont mind all the other outputs. However as @stek29 said, i want to know that everything is working. Then again, using bash or sh -x doesnt always provide the right messages. For some reason it looked like the ampersand wasnt recognized by the script because i didnt see it running in the background.